# How to retrieve the socket from CherryPy server

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, ssl, cherrypy

I've been playing around with CherryPy for a project. My use case requires that I use SSL directly through Python, so I'm using Python's SSLContext with CherryPy which works fine right now. However my use case will require reading the peer certificate at runtime, so I need access to the socket. I'm using the default server (_cpserver.Server) for CherryPy.

I've looked through the source and I see that CherryPy uses a worker model, so requests are handled by separate threads. Usually threaded requests are exposed via cherry.serving, but sockets are not included since the cheroot.HTTPRequest (which contains the socket via HTTPConnection object) is different from the cherrypy.Request that the server uses and the HTTPRequest object is not passed. Another option is the httpserver.gateway but request object doesn't appear here either.

Is there any other option than searching the requests.threads to find the socket or editing the source? There should be a thread-safe reference somewhere. Thanks.

Comment: What is the usecase you are talking about?

Comment: The use case would be restricting access based on fields in the certificate.